# Cmake not linking opencv libs to created static library

Tags: opencv, static, cmake

I am trying To create a static *.a lib from cmake . But It Is not linking the opencv libs to the static library as i get the error unknown refernce to cv:Mat .....etc.
The moment i changed add_library(Helper SHARED Helper.cpp Helper.h) it builds shared libs correctly as they are compiled correctly.
Can Anyone Tell me The problem and solutions.

```
-----------------------Cmake File---------------------------------

 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_library(Helper STATIC Helper.cpp Helper.h)

target_link_libraries(Helper ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Comment: Try set(OpenCV_STATIC ON) and then find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED core)

Answer (score 0):

try to add this config in cmake file

```
set(OpenCV_STATIC ON)
```

Comment: See my answer. Maybe you can add to it.

Answer (score 0):

### Question

I understood the question as following - You have a project to compile which its output is a Static Library. It is linked against OpenCV's static libraries. The expected output is a library which contains a single static library with all functions needed form OpenCV.

### Answer

When using Cmake add the following flag:

```
target_link_libraries(your_target_name -static)
```

This will make GCC / Clang to output a single static library.

I am not sure on how to achieve this in Windows.

### Remark About [@j.kahil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4506136/j-kahil) Answer

I don't think he meant to only use OpenCV's static libraries but he wanted the output of his project (Which is a Static Library) to include all needed static libraries of OpenCV.